# Can one edit a terminal buffer in Normal mode in NeoVim?

Tags: neovim

NeoVim's terminal mode is cool, but what I really would like is to
be able to switch to normal mode to edit terminal with normal mode commands, is it possible?

I realize that when in this terminal mode, all input is responsability of the terminal, so I see that a mode where input interaction travels between vim and the terminal shouldn't be simple, if it's doable at all, I'd just like to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible.

However, the user needs to use the `<C-\><C-n>` key combo first,
which will exit back to normal mode. Once in "normal" mode the user can navigate, set marks, visually select text, use registers to yank and paste the output somewhere else, etc.

If the user comes back to insert mode (`i` or `a`, e.g.) the cursor will come be back to the terminal command line.

For general information about the terminal emulator: `:h terminal-emulator`

For specific information on terminal's input: `:h terminal-emulator-input`. This section includes a bunch tips that might be handy, such as how to map `<C-\><C-n>` to `<esc>`.

Comment: Your NORMAL mode interactions doesn't edit anything, which is what I was interested in.

Comment: Not sure I understood your comment, @pepper_chico. However, you can transfer the text to a normal buffer and edit that.

Comment: Which is not editing **in** the terminal buffer.... The topic is about editing operations, not just the read-only ones.

Comment: Thanks. But you think about the terminal itself, you don't edit it, it outputs results, and there's nothing you can do against those results. That's why there's no meaning on editing the _terminal_ buffer. If you want to edit the output, you paste it on a buffer and edit it. But the terminal buffer can help, since it will treat the output as a buffer, you are able to search, mark, etc, (things that you can't do on a normal terminal). Once you have found what you want, move it to another buffer and edit it. By the way, this 'edited' output you won't be able to simply paste back to a terminal.

Comment: Anyway, sorry I was not able to answer you question. (:

Comment: You can edit the command line before you finish entering one command. OK, thanks.

Comment: I don't care about this feature anymore, it was curious to me at the time but today I'm much better of with tmux and vim/nvim than this embedded terminal. I don't hit such limitations with it.

Comment: Hey @pepper_chico I'm curious how you do use this feature in tmux? Can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: @ZzAntáres a handful of tmux tpm plugins and vim-tmux-navigator is a much better experience for me: https://github.com/oblitum/dotfiles/blob/archlinux/.tmux.conf#L51-L60 (note tmux-copycat sadly stopped working after tmux 2.4, for the moment).